# How Bind to the last parent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

In `{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TypeName}, AncestorLevel=???}` What value should I set to the `AncestorLevel` to reach to the last parent?

e.g. I want the last parent of `StackPanel` type.

Edit:So if it's not possible what can I do?

Comment: Does your structure change or would it be enough to find that element once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not possible to use FindAncestor to bind to the last ancestor, however it is possible to write a MarkupExtension which accomplishes this.

Here's a simple example which you could extend as is necessary

```
  class BindLastAncestor : MarkupExtension
  {
    public BindLastAncestor()
    {
    }

    public BindLastAncestor( Type ancestorType )
    {
    }

    public Type AncestorType
    {
      get;
      set;
    }

    public PropertyPath Path
    {
      get;
      set;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue( IServiceProvider serviceProvider )
    {
      var targetProvider = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));

      var target = targetProvider.TargetObject as DependencyObject;
      var targetProperty = targetProvider.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;
      if (target == null || targetProvider == null)
        throw new NotSupportedException();

      var ancestor = target;
      DependencyObject lastAncestor = null;

      while (ancestor != null)
      {
        if (ancestor.GetType() == this.AncestorType)
          lastAncestor = ancestor;

        ancestor = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(ancestor);
      }

      BindingOperations.SetBinding(target, targetProperty, new Binding { Path = this.Path, Source = lastAncestor });

      return target.GetValue(targetProperty);
    }
  }
```

Which could now be used like so, for example:

```
  <Grid x:Name="Grid1">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid2">
      <Grid x:Name="Grid3">
        <Grid x:Name="Grid4">
          <Grid x:Name="Grid5">
            <TextBox Text="{my:BindLastAncestor Path=Name, AncestorType=Grid}" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

Results in the TextBox getting 'Grid1'

Comment: Would this update if the structure were to change at runtime? (if not that would be a problem)

Comment: @H.B. If code is added for listening for the visual tree changes and re-running the ProvideValue function again yes, but its not in my simple implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible to specify that as far as i know.

Comment: no I want the last parent with the type I want like list parent with StackPanel type

Comment: does setting the ancestor level to a big number e.g "999" work?

Comment: @Zahid Sattar: No it does not.

Comment: @Zahid Sattar ya, given the code inside .NET no level will work, @Navid Rahmani your best bet is to write your own MarkupExtension for it